# WSO2 APIMgr Design Document

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Can someone send me link / pdf which samples the API Design Document. API can be RESTFul or SOAP. Help is much appreciated, please.

Regards, Sreedhar

Answer (score 1):

If video tutorials can assist you better, you can find them in [1]. These tutorials were recorded using the SaaS version of API Manager (API Cloud), they do apply to an on-premise deployment of API Manager as well.

[1] - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLp0TUr0bmhX49rEwMR7BDX2O9-iQHOOzN

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on this [quick start](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Quick+Start+Guide) guide to create APIs in API Manager. We provide a sample API with API Manager which will help you in understanding how API Manager works with APIs

Comment: Hi Abimaran, I am fine with APIs. I am looking for templates for Design Documentations / Functional Specs. If you can guide me on that, it would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by Design documentation and functional specs?

Comment: Following are requirements at a customer. Customer wants to extend entire product stack of WSO2. Hence, this implementation is crucial. I have enough documentation for other Middleware products (non-wso2) but not for WSO2.  1. Design document for publishing corporate libraries APIs to the API Gateway

2. Design document for enabling internal RESTFul and SOAP based APIs to be published and protected via the API Gateway
3. Design document for publishing API’s externally to Bank
4. Reference Architecture(s) which demonstrate best practices for using the API Gateway and Enterprise Service Bus

Comment: Contd from above.

5. Knowledge Transfer to Bank Team members on patterns and best practices for API Gateway and Enterprise Service Bus

6. Documentation of patterns and best practices for the API Gateway and Enterprise Service Bus

7. Documented consulting engagements on API Gateway and Enterprise Service Bus with teams outside of Application Infrastructure

8. Documentation of recommended tools for development and debugging of RESTful and SOAP APIs and interfaces

Comment: Any Help on above lines much appreciated to take the products to next level.

Comment: Abimaran,Any Clue on such documentation ?